# How to deal with wide and narrow buffers in c?

Tags: c, widechar, wchar

According to [embarcadero docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Unicode_Output_Format_Specifiers) we can use different Format Specifier to output a buffer to the console in my case I have a function that reads from a stream and outputs to the console but sometimes the stream is wide other times it is narrow and I have to know before hand what kind of stream is it to use the correct  format specifier `%s`or `%S`

```
    wchar_t res[8192]= {0};
    FILE * fd;
    if ( (fd = _wpopen(command, L"rb")) == NULL)
        return 0;

    wchar_t c;
    int i =0;
    while ( (c= fgetwc(fd)) != WEOF)
    {
        res[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    _pclose(fd);
    wprintf(L"%s", res);
```

Is there a way to know before hand if I should use `%s`or `%S` if not how do I ensure that it will always output the result properly

Comment: @Fe2O3 can you elaborate on what you mean by Case and p.u.n.c.t.u.a.t.i.o.n

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Your program is opening a file. Does it not know what type of contents that file has? If not, how do you expect to discern what type the contents are intended to be? Is it indicated in some metadata? Are you going to examine the file contents for clues? Will the user tell you? What do you mean by “beforehand”? You cannot know when you are writing the program what the contents of some file that does not exist yet will be.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i didn't mention that i am reading from a file and the function i am using is `_wpopen` which creates a pipe and the stream is unicode since the command is `c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /u /c <any command>`

Answer (score 1):

> I have to know before hand what kind of stream is it to use the correct format specifier

C lib has `int fwide(FILE *stream, int mode);` to set/report the orientation.  Use `fwide(stream, 0)` to report.

> The `fwide` function returns a value greater than zero if, after the call, the stream has wide orientation, a value less than zero if the stream has byte orientation, or zero if the stream has no orientation.

Comment: Note that the orientation of a _stream_ may change over its lifetime due to calls like `fwide()` and `freopen()`.

Comment: Does this work with streams from pipes?

Comment: I suspect it does yet C has no spec about _pipes_, but of _streams_.  Refer to your implementation's specs on pipes.